# Output Buffering Issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, output-buffering

I'm getting this strange issue with Codeigniter while returning a view. Here is my code

```
$data = $this->SomeModel->get(intval($id));
$html = $this->load->view('views/someview', array("data" => $data), TRUE);
```

What it is supposed to do is store the HTML from view in form of string on `$html` variable, but instead it's loading the whole view on my web browser.

Everything is working perfectly fine on my localhost, this issue only arises on the Linux server running PHP with the following configuration

```
apache2
PHP 5.6.39
```

Comment: So, the evaluated HTML is being displayed, or is it just the HTML markup?

Comment: @DFriend the HTML is being displayed

Comment: I asked the question poorly. Are you seeing **This is Bold** or are you seeing `<strong>This is Bold</strong>`

Comment: Try initializing your array before passing it to the view like this `$html = $this->load->view('your_view', $data, TRUE);` .. I'm not sure if this will make any difference or may work in your case but try it.

Comment: @DFriend I'm seeing **This is Bold**, the complete html is rendered on page instead of being saved in a variable

Comment: @SherifSalah the problem is not with the array, my guess is it has something to do with output buffering

Comment: What's the value of [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) in php.ini?

Comment: What's the code after `$html = $this->load->view...`?

Comment: I'm working on a linux server and using the third parameter a lot but never faced your problem.. i don't believe it has something to do with codeigniter itself.. maybe there is an error in your code before that i dunno.

Comment: @SherifSalah that's the problem, I also use third param a lot and never faced this problem, it's also working fine on localhost, the issue arise on server. So I'm also guessing the issue is somewhere in output buffering configuration